# How to use rawCollection for aggregate in meteor?

Tags: meteor, cron, bulk

I need to use `bulk` operations with aggregate in order to delete duplicates with a certain condition in my `database`. I tried to use `rawCollection()` but I don't really know how.

Here's the code I need to execute with `cron` every x hours

```
function removeDups() {
  var count = 0,
    collection = Beatmaps.rawCollection(),
    bulk = collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
  collection.aggregate([
    { '$sort': { 'difficultyrating': -1 }},
    { '$group': { '_id': '$beatmapset_id', 'ids': { '$push': '$_id' }, 'count': { '$sum': 1 }}},
    { '$match': { 'count': { '$gt': 1 }}}
  ]).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.ids.shift();
    bulk.find({'_id': { '$in': doc.ids }}).remove();
    count++;
    if(count === 100) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
  });

  if(count !== 0) {
    bulk.execute();
  }
}
```

but it produces an error: `Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined`

So what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, after  a bit of research I found similar question and here's what I did to make this work:

```
var aggregate = Meteor.wrapAsync(collection.aggregate, collection);
```

and then

```
aggregate(parameters).forEach(...);
```